# Edit Eloquent attributes in controller (relationship)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to change an eloquent instance in the controller, as in the following example:

```
$model = Model::find($id);
$model->relationship = array('param1','param2');
$model->toJson();
```

If I do check the `$model` on the second line I see that changes have been saved to `["attributes":protected]`, but the original relationship is still conserved in `["relations":protected]`, when I do `$model->toJson()` changes are lost.

How can I achieve this **in the controller**?

Comment: Might just be me but not 100% on what your asking. Are you asking how to persist / save the data you've changed?

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? Add relationship attribute? Remove existing relations?

Comment: I'm processing the relationship data in order to get it in a different manner into the view. The example shows what I want to achieve in 3 straightforward lines, the problem is that data I've changed is lost when I call ```->toJson();```

Comment: Have you tried `$model->save()`?

Comment: @BenHarold I don't want to save anything into database, I just want to process data on controller